# The method getEmailId() is undefined for the type Employee

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new at Spring Boot. I am trying to create a basic crud application using Angular and Spring Boot using this link

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/spring-boot-angular-8-crud-example-8aeafd47b54

I am getting an error in my EmployeeController.java class.
The method getEmailId() is undefined for the type Employee

Here is my EmployeeController.java code:

https://github.com/mehulk05/Spring-Boot-Angular-8-CRUD-Example/tree/master/springboot2-jpa-crud-example/src/main/java/net/guides/springboot2/springboot2jpacrudexample/controller

```
@PutMapping("/employees/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
        @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not 
       found for this id :: " + employeeId));

    employee.setEmailId(employeeDetails.getEmailId());
    employee.setLastName(employeeDetails.getLastName());
    employee.setFirstName(employeeDetails.getFirstName());
    final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedEmployee);
}
```

I am getting error in my methods getEmailId,getLastName,getFirstName.

I have defined these methods in my Employee.java

https://github.com/mehulk05/Spring-Boot-Angular-8-CRUD-Example/tree/master/springboot2-jpa-crud-example/src/main/java/net/guides/springboot2/springboot2jpacrudexample/model

```
@Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
public String getEmailId() {
    return emailId;
}
public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
    this.emailId = emailId;
}
```

I dont know why I am I getting this error. Please can anybody help me? I am new at this. Thanks.

Comment: Please post code(all respective methods) as well, where you are getting error ?

Comment: Please check my edit @YogendraR

Comment: Could you also post your body of put request ?

Comment: I just cloned your project and everything is ok